# get a specific element in a string

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to fetch the element id in SQL Server using sql query from a string or whatever the Id after string "Sub_"

Input:

> /Level_2000B/Level_2300/Seg_ABC/Sub_363

Output:
363

Note: Sub_ can be at any position

Comment: Consider using Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *'/'* delimiter exists between elements:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100)= N'/Level_2000B/Level_2300/Seg_ABC/Sub_363';

DECLARE @SlashPosition INT= CHARINDEX('/', @s, PATINDEX('%Sub_%', @s) + 4);
DECLARE @FirstStringOccurance INT= PATINDEX('%Sub_%', @s) + 4;

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@s, PATINDEX('%Sub_%', @s) + 4,
                  CASE WHEN @SlashPosition = 0 THEN LEN(@s)
                       ELSE @SlashPosition - @FirstStringOccurance
                  END);
```